# When do we actually need bank interleaving?

Tags: sdram, dram

Since common DRAM chips support burst transfer and hardware page size (row size) in a bank is quite large, we can amortize the charging & activating time over bytes in a long burst transfer.

I think it has the same effect of bank interleaving, which distributes successive addresses over different banks. And the performance is the same.

So why we need bank interleaving indeed?

Comment: An awful lot of accesses do not need those bursts anyways. And even with them, slap interleaving on top and you double the bandwidth.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Yeah, but interleaving successive addresses has the same effect as the burst transfer. If those accesses don't need bursts, they cannot benefit from interleaving too. I don't think that's the point.